# How develop a Angular 4 CLI in visual studio 2017 and IIS

Tags: angular, iis, visual-studio-2017, angular-cli

I installed a Angular 4 Application using the Angular CLI template for visual studio, in VS 2017.

That work OK, but use the IIS Express.

My goal is, that the Angular application get the information from a WEB.API installed in IIS.

I don't want to enable CORS or JSONP to access the information of the WEB API, because the end solution will be installed in the same IIS Server in the same domain.

Then, my question is:

**How to modify the Angular Application to be installed in the IIS during the DEVELOPMENT phase?**.

All the solutions that I found are related to deploy the Angular project to production. but I need in development. I was able to do that using the old quick-start of Angular 2 (now deprecated) Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to deal with CORS then you will need to build a MVC Application.  This means that you will only have one application/site in your IIS Server not two.

There is a well documented example from [candorDeveloper](http://candordeveloper.com/2017/04/12/how-to-use-angular-cli-with-visual-studio-2017/) that explains how he did it.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Angular run over its proper server or in IIS express, and the MVC application in IIS and these are two different domain. Also I use a WEB API. For a moment I enable CORS and configure it in a manner that I do not need to modify the code to disable it. any way thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes that is the way I would have done it. I'm currently building an API + Angular Site on the same IIS Server. You do need to have the CORS setup for both of them to work together.